# Ruby's "require" method with a forward slash in the string, what does that mean?

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
```

In this ruby method, there is a forward slash in the required method. I don't believe this is a folder path. I was wondering what this require method is doing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, actually this is a folder path.

Comment: So when I've installed these gems it installs itself in these folders? and where does the require method search for these?

Comment: look here - to confirm you [poltergeist / lib / capybara / poltergeist.rb](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist.rb)

Comment: in your [`$LOAD_PATH`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I've been searching everywhere for the answer. It makes so much sense now

Comment: This question could have been avoided by checking the documentation for the method first.

Answer (score 2):

yeah I checked the documentation it made it a little clearer. I understand that 'require' method will check the $LOAD_PATH global variable for my file, but my gems are not stored in any of the paths defined in $LOAD_PATH. So I still didn't understand how it was getting the files. But I think finally found my answer

> "When RubyGems activates a gem, it adds your package’s lib folder to the $LOAD_PATH ready to be required normally by another lib or application. It is safe to assume you can then require any file in your lib folder." - RubyGems Guide.

So I just have to check in the Gem's 'lib' to know what I can call with the 'require' method.